# Sigma-field generated by a class of sets cannot separate a particular pair of points

Tags: measure-theory

This is an exercise problem in David Pollard’s *A User’s Guide to Measure Theoretic Probability*. I’m stuck in it. Can anybody give a hint?

> Suppose a class of sets $\mathcal{E}$ cannot separate a particular pair of points $x$, $y$: for every $E$ in $\mathcal{E}$, either $\{x,y\}\subseteq E$ or $\{x,y\}\subseteq E^c$. Show that $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$ also cannot separate the pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class of all sets $A \in \sigma(\mathcal E)$ such that either $x \in A$ and $y \in A$ or  $y \notin A$ and $x \notin A$ is a sigma algebra which contains $\mathcal E$ . Hence it contains $\sigma(\mathcal E)$.

Comment: Thanks! I understand this generating class argument. But your answer seems to have a mistake? It should be “...either $x\in A$ and $y\in A$ or $x\notin A$ and $y\notin A$...”.

Comment: You are absolutely right!